# how to use AT-Command in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sms, serial-port, at-command

I tried to send commands to a GSM modem or phone with C# using this code but it`s not working! Can anybody tell me what should I do ?

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.PortName = "COM42";
sp.Open();
sp.Write("ATD09364191752");
```

Comment: that hasn't anything to do with c#, you should look up for a dictionary for at commands, and also how a sms has to be encoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not writing a newline after the ATD command.  (I think you have to.)
2. You don't call `sp.Flush()`, so the command may be getting stuck in a buffer.  Try adding this call after the `Write()` call.

Comment: Not flush.  Yes on the newline, use WriteLine().  A bit fuzzy on a country where a phone number starts with a zero and doesn't have enough digits to make an international call :)

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on all default settings for baud-rate, handshake protocols etc. You may want to check the modem docs about those.

Comment: Yes, and Handshake.  Or the DtrEnable property.